# Visual studio 2013 and bootstrap 3 support out of the box?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've read that visual studio supports bootstrap 3, but it's right out of the box? Like, when you create an asp.net project, it already comes with the .css and .js files? Or do you have to download bootstrap using nuget (like i did)?

I created a asp.net template project and an empty project and didn't see the files...something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: by definition you should expect an "empty project" to be empty.  But it all depends on the template you use to create your project.  Some may include it, and some won't.

Comment: how hard is it to go to bootstrap.com and make you own css file thereafter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a MVC project in VS 2013 by

1. Going to File then New then Project
2. Then selecting Templates
3. ASP.NET Web Application
4. Then in the next window selecting an MVC project.

In the Content folder there is bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css v3.0.0. It has bootstrap.js and the min version in the Scripts folder.

You may have created a VS 2012 project in the submenu of step three. This will use a legacy template to create your project.

Comment: I've created a vs 2013 asp.net web forms project. The bootstrap only comes with a mvc project?

Comment: @JoaoVictor No, it comes with all non-empty MVC, Web Pages, and Web Forms projects. Just experiment. Or add Bootstrap to an empty project via NuGet.

Comment: Definitely comes with Forms. There is nothing wrong with using the NuGet package to get it. But it is odd that it isn't working for you.

Comment: Hmmm...weird..i didn't see any bootstrap files in my non-empty asp.net web-forms project...i'll try again in a few minutes...but then again, i thought it would be hard to add with nuget...easy as hell.

Comment: @Sobieck00 i've tested it again and it worked. I don't know what went wrong but the files are there. Thanks for the help!